# Will the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint pass the same nameidentifier through as Access Control Services for the same Microsoft Account?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

We are currently using Azure Access Control Services (***.accesscontrol.windows.net) to allow customers with personally-managed Microsoft Accounts (Identity Provider) to sign in to our customer self-service portals (Relying Party Applications), which are Angular apps powered by Web API services. In our Access Control Services we are currently passing through the nameidentifier `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier` claim from Windows Live ID to the relying party APIs, which match that token to an identity in our applications.

We are looking to support both Enterprise and Personal Microsoft Accounts with the [Azure AD v2.0 service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-dotnet-api/), but do not understand how to migrate our existing users to the new system. The code examples suggest that the [OWIN middleware](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebAPI-DotNet/blob/complete/TodoListService/Startup.cs#L17) returns the [NameIdentifier claim](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebAPI-DotNet/blob/complete/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs#L43) from the user's Identity Provider, but if that Identity Provider is the same Microsoft Account (aka Windows Live ID), will that be the same NameIdentifier we are currently receiving via Access Control Services pass-through?

Any help and/or documentation that clarifies how this transition is intended to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the nameidentifier coming out of ACS is the randomly generated value then you're kind of stuck because that value is unique to the ACS/RP/User. If it's returning the actual Live ID then it'll obviously only match if the Azure AD user has the same email address.

I don't know if any documentation out there that describes how to handle this situation. My recommendation is to just require a one-time authentication from each source within the same session and marry the two results. That would basically mean

1. authenticate to Azure AD
2. Your app: Hey you don't have any user details, do you want to associate a Live ID?
3. Authenticate Live ID
4. Associate Live ID with Azure AD

Then if they want to sign in with either accounts in the future you have a link between the two.

Comment: This is correct. However, after trying it we learned that a valid nameidentifier claim does include the primary email address of these users, which may help our migration as we have kept this data. However, for it to work 100% of the time, you are correct that we need an association flow.